# Macos Ventura, #error SDL for Mac OS X only supports deploying on 10.7 and above

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2, macos-ventura

I just updated to Macos Ventura, however when I try to compile my project which was compiling cleanly before I updated, I get the below error message. Here is one of the outputs of the error message:

```bash
In file included from /opt/homebrew/include/SDL2/SDL_config.h:33,
                 from /opt/homebrew/include/SDL2/SDL_stdinc.h:31,
                 from /opt/homebrew/include/SDL2/SDL_main.h:25,
                 from /opt/homebrew/include/SDL2/SDL.h:32,
                 from ../include/gfc_audio.h:4,
                 from gfc_audio.c:4:
/opt/homebrew/include/SDL2/SDL_platform.h:112:3: error: #error SDL for Mac OS X only supports deploying on 10.7 and above.
  112 | # error SDL for Mac OS X only supports deploying on 10.7 and above.
      |   ^~~~~
```

Also I am using gcc-12 from homebrew and reinstalled gcc and sdl if that helps.

Comment: So what's the value of the `CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some research, according to this [github issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/113968), XCode 14.1 has not been released and is still in release candidate state. After the release of XCode 14.1 it should be working fine.